# How to solve: Version: 7.8.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm developing an app on Android studio, but when I tried to run Firebase FCM sdk,
I got the message: **Version: 7.8.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.**

How can I fix it?

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 10096
        versionName "1.0.9.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Fixes "Duplicate files copied in APK" build bug
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
dependencies {

    // Pushy SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.43'

    // AppCompat v7 Dependency
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    // Google Play Services Dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'

    // All .jar files in ./libs
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my build.gradle-master:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error log said, you should change the version in `build.gradle`.

```
    // Google Play Services Dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
```

Comment: Message: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.